# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split')

Tags: angular, typescript, null, pipe, angular8

ShortName-Pipe.ts

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'shortName'
})

export class ShortNamePipe implements PipeTransform { 

 transform(fullName: string, numChars: number = 2): any

 return fullName.split(' ')    
 .slice (0, numChars)    
 .map(n => n[e].toUpperCase())
 .join('');

}
```

App.component.ts

```
getShortName (fullName) {
    return fullName.split(' ').map(n => n[0]);
}
```

I tried adding null and undefined checks as well but was not able to get rid of error, it shows blank value for the first time when site loads and works fine after the refresh. But want to get rid of these error at first place

Answer (score 0):

Try making this one change

```
transform(fullName: string, numChars: number = 2): any {
 if (!fullName) {
   return "";
 } 
 return fullName.split(' ')    
 .slice (0, numChars)    
 .map(n => n[e].toUpperCase())
 .join('');

}
```

Comment: After adding this lines the error is not displayed but the issue is same that it's not getting displayed on first time and works after the refresh

Comment: I'm not sure why it's working for the first time and on refresh it's working, but I have a doubt in your code snippet. Do you have any specific reason for doing `n[e].toUpperCase()`, Coz I don't see anywhere `e` being initialised. 

If you want to generate something like an acronym then try doing `a[0].toUpperCase()`.
The output that you expect from this would be, 

Input: Stackoverflow Awesome, numChars = 2
Output: SA

If you're expecting something different it would be better if you can give me an example of input and output.

Comment: My bad in the code it is n[0] and not n[e] made an typing error and the code where I have used is  <p-overlayPanel[style] ="width: '550px" #op1>

<div class="ProfileImage2">

|{{ (this.person?.displayName) | shortName: 2 }}

</div>

<div>

<span class="PersonNameDialog">{{this.person?.displayName}</span>

<br>

<span class="PersonEmailDialog">{{this.person?.email}}</span>

</div>

</p-overlayPanel>

Comment: Looks fine, can you give an example of expected output for any input? and are you facing any issues running with this?

Comment: Expected output should come as JJ inside a round circle as a user profile, as soon as I run the site but it's showing the blank circle as a debug the code. The JJ comes after I refresh the site but not when I debug the code for the first time.

Comment: This is something to do with change detection, Try making this change to you pipe annotation.

@Pipe({
  name: 'shortName',
  pure: false
})

Comment: Added but it didn't work :(